# break when any address is assigned a value within a certain range

Tags: debugging, memory, assembly, lldb

I am trying to debug an issue in lldb where I have some memory location that is getting updated to point into a location of memory that it should not be.  I know that if anything points outside of a certain range of memory, then we are going to have an issue.  Is it possible to set something similar to a watchpoint such that execution breaks if any address gets updated to point outside a particular range?  Perhaps there is a way to do this with a python script that I can then import into lldb?

Comment: In general you can't know if a given value is an address until its used as an address.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can watch if *any* address gets updated to point outside a particular range - I guess a CPU simulator or valgrind can do this - but you can watch if any of a specified set of pointer-sized pieces of memory point outside a particular range by setting watchpoints and adding conditions.